# Audio tag doesn't work in Active admin, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, activeadmin, carrierwave

I'm have a model named Point which has :audio field related to carrierwave for uploading audio files. I'm using ActiveAdmin to create a new point. I'm trying to show point objects in active admin, everything works fine except audio field. Activeadmin shows uploaded audio file's name when i do it without audio_tag, but with audio tag it's nothing showed. Here's the code. Thanks in advance!

```
class Point < ActiveRecord::Base

mount_uploader :audio, FileUploader 
end  

class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :file

  def extension_white_list
    %w(wma wav ogg oga mp3 3gp)   
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"   
  end 
  end

ActiveAdmin.register Point do

  menu label: 'points'

  permit_params :title, :description, :audio, :altitude, :latitude, :longitude, :distance_visible, :coordinates


  form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
    f.inputs "Location" do
      f.input :title, label: "Title"
      f.input :description, :as => :text, label: "Description"

      f.input :altitude, label: "Altidue"
      f.input :latitude, label: "Latitude"
      f.input :longitude, label: "Longitude"
      f.input :distance_visible, label: "Distance"

      f.input :audio, label: "Audio file"
      end 
   f.actions
   end

  show do
    attributes_table do
      row :title
      row :description
      row :audio do |item|
        audio_tag item.audio
      end
    end   
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to check in different browser because some browser doesn't support audio tag or use any jquery plugin to play audio file like jplayer, mediaelementplayer etc..

Answer (score 1):

thuc tran was close, but the syntax is off as that will add `controls:true` to the audio file path that it looks up. It looks like this:

`audio_tag: item.audio, controls: true`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass :controls options to audio_tag:
audio_tag(item.audio, controls: true)